# Laser-induced heat flow in metal

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, metals

If you shine a laser on metal so the laser beam is perpendicular to the surface, will heat flow radially outward from the laser spot equally in all directions? If it hits the metal at an angle of incidence of 45 degrees, will more heat flow in the direction the laser is pointing?

Answer (score 1):

I will make an interpretation on heat-source density. For perpendicular incidence, yes, your heat-source density has a cillindrical symmetry, so will flow radially equally. For 45° incidence, if assuming a Gaussian profile, in the plane of incidence all you have is a Gaussian distribution. Then your heat-source density will just be a 2D elliptical Gaussian distribution. If I would have to guess heat flow (I cannot solve the heat equation in my mind), I would guess it will be stronger in the direction perpendicular to the plane of incidence as the gradient is much higher (so, from the hottest central spot, to the outer, cold edge, there is a stronger gradient so heat will flow more readily to equalize those regions). I am of course assuming you want heat flow to neighbouring regions, and not heat-source density.